# How to obtain the source IP from a Wireshark dump of an HTTP GET request

Tags: http, networking, ip, wireshark

I'm currently studying for my test but I can't seem to figure this one out. I'm asked to figure out the source IP address out of this wireshark frame (using the reference image only), how would I be going about this?

[image: Wireshark]

Comment: Hint: the first 54 bytes *include* the [IP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_header) and [TCP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure). The HTTP data starts at the 55th byte (`GET ...`).  The source/destination IP addresses are in the IP header, and the source/destination port numbers are in the TCP header. Good luck with your test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source IP address is 172.22.7.134.

e0 3f 49 09 60 68 c8 2a 14 55 eb bd 08 00 - First 14 bytes will be layer 2 Ethernet frame.

[image]

Next 20 bytes belongs to IP version 4 where you can get source IP address and destination IP address.

[image]

45 - 1 Byte – version which is 4 and header length 5

00 – 1 Byte  - DSCP value

01 a3 – 2 bytes – Total length : which is 419

18 84 – 2 bytes – identification

40 00 – flag and fragment offset

80 – time to live 128

06 – protocol : TCP (6)

00 00 – header checksum

ac 16 07 86 – Source IP address in hex which is 172.22.7.134 in dotted decimal format.

91 21 05 ad – Destination IP address in hex which is 145.33.5.173 in dotted decimal format.

Source IP address is 172.22.7.134 and your answer is located here,
[image]