# Simulate an HTTP/2 stream with pcap4j

Tags: wireshark, libpcap, pcap4j

I'm trying to capture the unencrypted bytes of a TLS connection and record them into a cap file for analysis of the HTTP/2 traffic.  There are a lot of assumptions I am making that this is even possible.  But I'm willing to fudge almost everything below the HTTP/2 layer if I can see that traffic in a useful tool like Wireshark.

https://github.com/yschimke/okhttp/commit/c6b0b4c0ba3b59d44cf292955eef2685ed6094e7#diff-d4b38ff70d61641e49af93db2892080f47a2480af92ca151b2daabb50bbc459b

My approach eventually boils down to

```
return object : DelegatingSSLSocket(socket) {
   override fun getInputStream(): InputStream {
     return object : FilterInputStream(socket.inputStream) {
       override fun read(b: ByteArray, off: Int, len: Int): Int {
         return super.read(b, off, len).also { readLen ->
           dumper.dump(
             ipv4ReadPacketBuilder.payloadBuilder(
               tcpReadPacketBuilder
                 .payloadBuilder(
                   UnknownPacket.Builder().rawData(
                     b.sliceArray(off.rangeTo(off + readLen))
                   )
                 )
             )
               .build()
           )
         }
       }
     }
   }

   override fun getOutputStream(): OutputStream {
     return object : FilterOutputStream(socket.outputStream) {
       override fun write(b: ByteArray, off: Int, len: Int) {
         super.write(b, off, len)

         dumper.dump(
           ipv4WritePacketBuilder.payloadBuilder(
             tcpWritePacketBuilder
               .payloadBuilder(
                 UnknownPacket.Builder().rawData(b.sliceArray(off.rangeTo(off + len)))
               )
           )
             .build()
         )
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Does anyone have any advice on pcap4j or pcap files generally to see what I'm doing wrong?

The packets I'm writing are IPv4>TCP>Data

[image: tcp dump packets]

But Wireshark shows

[image: HTTP/2 preamble]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IPv4, Version is always equal to 4.  Your image states that you are trying to write IPv4 Header but hex codes shows that it is not the IPv4 header.

[image]

First highlighted number is 56. Instead of 5 it should be 4. Hence Wireshark is unable to detect it as a IPv4 packet.

[image]

Refer my below link, it will help you to understand the sample format.

[How to obtain the source IP from a Wireshark dump of an HTTP GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65726556/how-to-obtain-the-source-ip-from-a-wireshark-dump-of-an-http-get-request/65772296#65772296)

For TCP, it should be 06 instead of bb.

[image]

Also your source IP is 0.0.0.0. It will not generate any error but you can change it as per your requirement.

[image]