# How many http and https connections established in wireshark?

Tags: http, wireshark

I ran  wireshark for a while and opened a few webpages now my class assignment is asking me to find out the number of http and https connections established. Can you suggest commands or filters to find these out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is connection-less, that means client and server knows about each other during current request and response only. You can open the .pcapng file and then

- Click on “Statistics”
- Select “HTTP”
- Select “Packet Counter“

[image]

In my case, I can 14 requests and 14 responses. (Success 2xx).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing this up. Can you explain how the same could be done for HTTPS because in statistics I can only see HTTP  and HTTP2

Comment: You can get client hello :  "ssl.handshake.type == 1"

Comment: You can get server hello :  "ssl.handshake.type == 2"

Comment: Complete list is available on https://davidwzhang.com/2018/03/16/wireshark-filter-for-ssl-traffic/

Comment: For TLS/SSL Handshake detail analysis in Wireshark, Refer : https://render-prd-trops.events.ibm.com/support/pages/sites/default/files/inline-files/$FILE/SSL_handshake_analysis.pdf